# iPhone app is self-controlling. why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, ibaction

i have a simple iPhone app. but it is controlling itself without IBAction. suspicious part of codes is this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:mMoviePlayer];
```

earlier version than iOS 4.2, the app is acting as i expected. but iOS 4.2 and next versions , the selector function is called without touched or any other IBAction. so why is it called ?

Comment: Can you clarify under what circumstances this selector is called? Does it happen every time you run the app, or after certain other actions have taken place? Does it call just once?

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is adding an observer to the system's notification center. So when the phone receives a notification, your code automatically performs the selector with that object.

Likely what's going on is that the types of notifications sent by the `NSNotificationCenter` has changed in iOS 4.2

Comment: well actually the problem was that i should use MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. after iOS 4, the first class is BETTER.[link](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shunsuk/20100625/1277471366)

Comment: I found the problem. so long it was MPMoviePlayerController. its shouldautoplay property is TRUE on default. that`s why the movies played without being touched.